# Alternative to forecast() and ets() in Python?

Tags: r, forecasting, python

I'm looking for a Python alternative to R's ETS() from forecast().

It's my understanding that ETS() is one of the best performing forecasting program and I would like to use it. However I am extremely uncomfortable using R and I already have all my data cleaned and set up in Python.

Does anyone know any other packages similar to ETS?

Comment: It would be better to ask this over on StackOverflow. Technically this type of question is no longer allowed on CV, it is too programming focused. That said, last time I checked exponential smoothing/Forecasting are on the to-do list for statsmodels.

Comment: Sorry, I would have had I known. In fact I would have preferred to have asked on StackOverflow but I thought I would get told off and asked to post here haha!

Comment: I think there is exponential smoothing in Pandas. It would probably be easiest to tag a SO question with Pandas (they are very active over there).

Answer (score 4):

There is an open PR to add full ETS functionality to statsmodels [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1489). I ran out of steam trying to code up all the heuristics for optimization that Hyndman suggests to make it less fragile. If someone wants to take up the torch here, I have some uncommitted code and thoughts on how to proceed.

Comment: This has been pull requested in.